# Create padding when fixed aspect ratio QWidget cannot fill entire window

Tags: python, pyqt5

A custom widget (class name MyLabel, inherits QLabel) has a fixed aspect ratio 16:9.

When I resize my window, the label is top-left aligned unless the window happens to be 16:9, in which case it fills the window perfectly.

How do I get the label to be centered? I have looked at size policies, alignments, using spaceitems and stretch, but I cannot seem to get it working as desired.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.Qt import QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgreen") # Just for visibility

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        # Size of 16:9 and scale it to the new size maintaining aspect ratio.
        new_size = QSize(16, 9)
        new_size.scale(event.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.resize(new_size)
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)

        # Main widget and layout, and set as centralWidget
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        # Add button to main_layout
        label = MyLabel("Hello World")
        self.main_layout.addWidget(label)

        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Examples of desired outcome:

[image]

[image]

Examples of actual outcome:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not easy to correctly implement a resizable widget that keeps aspect ratio on Qt (actually, it's sometimes almost impossible). Keep also in mind that changing the size within a `resizeEvent()` is [highly discouraged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop), as it can lead to infinite recursion. The question is: are you using a QLabel just for example purposes and you'll actually use a custom widget, or you absolutely need that class? Or are you trying to show a scaled image that keeps aspect ratio?

Comment: Thank you for commenting @musicamante. In my actual problem, I am using opencv to display video in a widget that indeed inherits qlabel. I am open to any other suggestions here. I have one implementation where I actually dusctomized the resizeevent such that the entire mainwindow would keep the aspect ratio, but this is not very nice and becomes a bit weird when snapping to sides, top or bottom.

Comment: Mmh. That can become tricky, as it depends on how opencv actually *uses* the QLabel. Besides the positioning issue, does your implementation work fine? I mean, does the video correctly show (position and size), or is it cropped (possibly on its left/bottom)?

Comment: Actually, I read a frame an put it in a pixmap, so it's no problem. If we solve the example in this question, we are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt unfortunately doesn't provide a straight forward solution for widgets that require a fixed aspect ratio.

There are some traces in old documentation, but the main problem is that:

- all functions related to aspect ratio (`hasHeightForWidth()` etc) for widgets, layouts and size policies are only considered for the size hint, so no constraint is available if the widget is manually resized by the layout;
- as the [documentation reports](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) changing the geometry of a widget within the `moveEvent()` or `resizeEvent()` might lead to infinite recursion;
- it's not possible to (correctly) control the size growth or shrinking while keeping aspect ratio;

For the sake of completeness, here's a partial solution to this issue, but be aware that QLabel is a very peculiar widget that has some constraints related to its text representation (most importantly, with rich text and/or word wrap).

```
class MyLabel(QLabel):
    lastRect = None
    isResizing = False
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgreen")
        self.setScaledContents(True)

    def restoreRatio(self, lastRect=None):
        if self.isResizing:
            return
        rect = QRect(QPoint(), 
            QSize(16, 9).scaled(self.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        if not lastRect:
            lastRect = self.geometry()
        rect.moveCenter(lastRect.center())
        if rect != lastRect:
            self.isResizing = True
            self.setGeometry(rect)
            self.isResizing = False
        self.lastRect = None

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return True

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        if self.pixmap():
            return width * self.pixmap().height() / self.pixmap().width()
        return width * 9 / 16

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self.pixmap():
            return self.pixmap().size()
        return QSize(160, 90)

    def moveEvent(self, event):
        self.lastRect = self.geometry()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.restoreRatio(self.lastRect)
```

Since the purpose is to display an image, another possibility is to manually paint everything on your own, for which you don't need a QLabel at all, and you can just override the `paintEvent` of a QWidget, but for performance purposes it could be slightly better to use a container widget with a child QLabel: this would theoretically make things a bit faster, as all the computation is completely done in Qt:

```
class ParentedLabel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, pixmap=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.child = QLabel(self, scaledContents=True)
        if pixmap:
            self.child.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.child.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.updateGeometry()

    def updateChild(self):
        if self.child.pixmap():
            r = self.child.pixmap().rect()
            size = self.child.pixmap().size().scaled(
                self.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            r = QRect(QPoint(), size)
            r.moveCenter(self.rect().center())
            self.child.setGeometry(r)

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return bool(self.child.pixmap())

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        return width * self.child.pixmap().height() / self.child.pixmap().width()

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self.child.pixmap():
            return self.child.pixmap().size()
        return QSize(160, 90)

    def moveEvent(self, event):
        self.updateChild()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.updateChild()
```

Finally, another possibility is to use a QGraphicsView, which is probably the faster approach of all, with a small drawback: the image shown based on the given size hint will probably be slightly smaller (a couple of pixels) than the original, with the result that it will seem a bit "out of focus" due to the resizing.

```
class ViewLabel(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, pixmap=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet('ViewLabel { border: 0px solid none; }')
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.setScene(scene)
        self.pixmapItem = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        self.pixmapItem.setTransformationMode(Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        scene.addItem(self.pixmapItem)

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self.pixmapItem.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.updateGeometry()
        self.updateScene()

    def updateScene(self):
        self.fitInView(self.pixmapItem, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return not bool(self.pixmapItem.pixmap().isNull())

    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        return width * self.pixmapItem.pixmap().height() / self.pixmapItem.pixmap().width()

    def sizeHint(self):
        if not self.pixmapItem.pixmap().isNull():
            return self.pixmapItem.pixmap().size()
        return QSize(160, 90)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.updateScene()
```